# Deleting items from a ListView using a custom BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, listview

I want the user to click a button ,
Remove item from list
I 've read a lot of questions, to remove the list item .
But I can not find any answer to my problem.
I do not know how to be able to structure my program
(According to the code below)
Anyone know what I need to add ?

java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_qusition);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter=new Myadapter(getApplicationContext());
    String qustion=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.qustion);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
 }


public class Myadapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{


    LayoutInflater myInflater;




    public Myadapter(Context context) {
        myInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return qustion.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         final ViewHolder Holder;

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            Holder=new ViewHolder();
            convertView=myInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_custom_layout,null );
            Holder.qustion=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_qustion);
            Holder.delete=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imag_delete);
            Holder.heart=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imag_heart);
            Holder.share=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imag_share);

            convertView.setTag(Holder);

        }
        else
            Holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    Holder.qustion.setTextSize(size);
        Holder.qustion.setText(qustion[position]);

    //}
  Holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                //-----------delete item list


            }
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array `qustion` that represents the data in your adapter. What you would need to do is find out which index was deleted and remove that index from your array. This would be easier if your array was changed to an ArrayList. After removing the index call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your adapter to update the view.

Comment: I have several buttons on a list item
Because of this , I can not use the Array List

Comment: Why can't you use an ArrayList? Your current code won't work anyway, qustion is declared in the scope of your activity's onCreate, it is not accessible in your adapter and you didn't even declare it as an array. Declare an ArrayList<String> as a class variable to either your activity or your adapter and initialize it using the string array you retrieve from resources, then you can remove items from it.

Comment: Thanks a lot
Your comments ,
It helped me